# Config element \"FrameworkDataImageContentInterface\" is not declared in GraphQL schema

Tags: magento2, graphql, vue-storefront

This is error appeared when calling productDetail GraphQL API. Anyone know how to solve it?

Request

```
{"sku":{"eq":"1xxxx-xxx-xxx"}},"configurations":[]},{"productDetail":"productDetail"},{}
```

Response as image below
[image]

Comment: can you provide which query you are running?

Comment: i am running this API 
https://github.com/vuestorefront/magento2/blob/main/packages/api-client/src/api/productDetails/productDetailsQuery.ts